# What is the closure of the interval in the topology generated by this base?

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathscr B $ be a collection of all open intervals on $\mathbb R$ with the form $(a, b)$ where $-\infty < a<0<b<\infty $. $\mathscr B $ is a base for a topology on $\mathbb R$
What is the closure of $(-2,-1) \cup (1, 2)$ generated by this base?

The closure of a set is a union of itself and the adherent points (or the cluster points). However, I am not sure   $(-2,-1) \cup (1, 2)$ how this union was generated by the given base, because in this topology nonempty open sets are always open intervals about zero.
Advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean $(-2, -1)\cup(1,2)$? Because the intersection of $(-2,-1)$ and $(1,2)$ is empty; the closure of the empty set in any topology is itself

Comment: Yes, thank you @Quoka , I meant "union".

Comment: @ronno: Thanks, I overlooked that part.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A = (-2, -1) \cup (1, 2)$. Then $\overline{A} = (\operatorname{int} (A^\complement))^\complement$, where $\operatorname{int} C$ is the interior of $C$, and is given by $\bigcup\ \{B \in \mathscr{B} \mid B \subseteq C\}$. If $(a, b) \in \mathscr{B}$ and $(a, b) \subseteq A^\complement = [-1,1] \cup [2,\infty) \cup (-\infty, 2]$ then $-1 \le a$ and $b \le 1$, so $(a, b) \subseteq (-1, 1)$.
On the other hand, $(-1, 1) \in \mathscr{B}$. So $\operatorname{int} A^\complement = (-1, 1)$, which implies that $\overline{A} = (-1, 1)^\complement = (-\infty, -1] \cup [1, \infty)$.

Comment: Thank you!!!!! I figure that out too.

Answer (score 0):

The closure of a set $S$ is the intersection of all closed sets containig $S$. In other words, it is the smallest closed set containing $S$. Recall that a set is closed $\iff$ it's complement is open.

Show that $[-2, -1]\cup[1,2]$ is closed. Therefore, the closure of $(-2, -1)\cup (1,2)$ must be contained in $[-2, -1]\cup[1,2]$.

Then, you are left with only finitely many options for the closure:

- $[-2, -1]\cup[1,2]$
- $(-2, -1]\cup[1,2]$
- $[-2, -1)\cup[1,2]$
- $(-2, -1)\cup[1,2]$
- $[-2, -1]\cup(1,2]$
- ...
- $(-2, -1)\cup (1,2)$.

Justify why all but $[-2,-1]\cup [1,2]$ are not closed. To see that, for instance, $(-2, -1)\cup [1,2)$ is not closed, we show that it's complement $A = (-\infty, -2]\cup (-1,1)\cup (2, \infty)$ is not open. Indeed, if it where open then there would exist an open interval $(a,b)$ with $2\in (a,b) \subseteq A$ which is impossible.

The method I'm presenting assumes you have basically only seen the definition of a topology. If you have a few results, you can clean up the proof.